# Hide Product Catalog standard dashlet for all users in Sugarcrm

Tags: hide, sugarcrm, dashlet

How can i hide a standard dashlet named "Product Catalog" from the list which gets displayed in the drawer named "Add a Sugar Dashlet". "Add a Sugar Dashlet" drawer gets displayed when user tries to add a dashlet in any dashbaord in Sugarcrm. Hiding should be done in an upgrade safe way.

Note: I am using Sugarcrm Ver 8.0.0 PRO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to accomplish this is by creating a custom override of the DashletselectView where you filter out the Dashlet in question.
The code below does so by overriding an internal function of the view, post-processing its results.

`custom/clients/base/views/dashletselect/dashletselect.js`

```
({
    extendsFrom: "DashletselectView",

    _getDashlets: function() {
        var dashlets = this._super("_getDashlets", arguments);
        return _.filter(dashlets, function (d) { return d.type !== "product-catalog-dashlet"; });
    },
})
```

Then run *Quick Repair & Rebuild* so that Sugar detects the presence of the custom  file and loads it.